# Python packages need to be imported when used for every script my application has?

Tags: python

I am developing my first application with Python. Briefly, the structure consists of the main.py script that calls functions from other scripts.

When importing packages (e.g. sys, pandas etc), do I have to do this for every script I developed or can I do this once in main.py and then use them when needed in the other scripts?

Comment: You should generally import a package in the module where it's needed.  You *can* stick all your imports into one module and then import all the imports from that module, but the more tricky you try to get with it the more likely you'll end up with some kind of circular import nightmare.  Don't do it unless you've thought it out really carefully and have a really good reason.

Comment: It is better to import in every module where it's needed. This makes the dependencies more transparent and you do not have to follow chains of imports. The Python interpreter is supporting this by efficient caching and not reading files multiple times.